# I'm trying to deploy my site to vercel but it kips giving this error

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, vercel, sanity

```
[15:37:42.508] Cloning github.com/Tomiwakukoyi/shopit (Branch: main, Commit: b447242)
[15:37:42.746] Previous build cache not available
[15:37:42.919] Cloning completed: 411.205ms
[15:37:43.019] Running "vercel build"
[15:37:43.429] Vercel CLI 28.13.2
[15:37:43.643] Installing dependencies...
[15:37:45.251] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[15:37:45.253] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! 
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! While resolving: next-sanity-image@3.2.1
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! Found: @sanity/client@3.4.1
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^3.2.0" from the root project
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! 
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! node_modules/next-sanity-image
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR!   next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! 
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sanity/client@2.23.2
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR!   peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
[15:37:45.254] npm ERR!   node_modules/next-sanity-image
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR!     next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! 
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! 
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[15:37:45.255] 
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[15:37:45.255] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-01-30T14_37_43_868Z-debug-0.log
[15:37:45.273] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I tried to deploy my site to Vercel through the github repo all on the vercel website but i keep getting that error above and im absolutely lost.
I dont know what to do to move forward with it.

Comment: is it the same when you build locally?

Comment: i dont think so